# How to display a grid keeping 16:9 aspect ratio?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to display a grid of live cameras.

I need two responsive columns keeping 16:9 aspect ratio for the items.

My code is:

```
<div class="grid">

  <div class="item" *ngFor="let i of cameras">
    <iframe [src]="this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(i.url)"
            scrolling="no"
            frameBorder="0"
            allow="autoplay; encrypted-media">
            </iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(160px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;

  .item {
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
  }

  .item:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding-bottom: calc(9/16 * 50%);
  }

  iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    overflow:auto !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
  }
}
```

The problem is how to keep the 16:9 aspect ratio.

[image: example]

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a flex container (with flex-direction and flex-wrap) and let the items maintain their aspects?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @MaximSaplin I'm not familiar with flexbox... Will check this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Tricks has a cool trick that has helped me with a similar issue before:

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
  <iframe width="560" height="349" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: tried this approach and got similiar result as my original post... the `padding-bottom` param creates an empty space below the frame...